# Android resize entirely layout with all his views dynamically

Tags: java, android

I have added in a Relative Layout some ImageViews with some Buttons and gave them some width and high values.I have tested the application on a nexus 7 and everything looks great but when I tested on other devices some functions like a popUpWindow or even some Views look wrong.Is there a way how to resise a layout with all his views dynamically to fit every device I test on ?

Comment: Android developer pages have some pretty useful and clear guides on how to support multiple devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values you're using are probably not what you're looking for. Instead, you may mean to use `wrap_content` or `match_parent`.

Please have a look at this [tutorial on layouts](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) and absorb and practice some of that before immediately asking for help. You got this!